# Unable to download files from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to download files from Azure Blob Storage container that is from public account. I am able to access and list files from my Ubuntu server with command below

```
az storage blob list --account-name dbacademy --container-name spark-ui-simulator --prefix global-sales/transactions/ --output table
```

But when I try to use below command to download files it runs but no files are downloaded

```
./azcopy copy "https://dbacademy.blob.core.windows.net/spark-ui-simulator/global-sales/transactions/*" /home/ubuntu/transactions/
```

Comment: this really belongs on [su] or [sf] - it's about cloud infrastructure and related tools, and not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried the same in my environment got the result below:***

In storage account created a folder and uploaded files like below:

[image]

Run the below command to download the file in Linux like below:

```
azcopy copy "https://stss.blob.core.windows.net/contaier/folder1/folder2/*" /home/imran123/imr
```

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/HSbGp8N.png)]

Files are downloaded successfully like below:

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/7kqP4jw.png)]

Make sure to replace Blob Storage  `<container-name>` with the name of the container containing the files, and `<blob-path>` with the specific path or prefix of the files you want to download. Also, ensure that the local directory (`/home/ubuntu/transactions/`) exists and is writable.

Download the latest version of Azcopy using the below Linux command:

```
curl -L https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-linux -o azcopy_linux_amd64.tar.gz
tar -xf azcopy_linux_amd64.tar.gz --strip-components=1
chmod +x ./azcopy
sudo mv ./azcopy /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: Please note that 1) the question is off-topic, as it's not a programming question (it belongs on [sf] or [su]; and 2) please refrain from posting images of text - that is not useful for many people, and can't be copy/pasted. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many other reasons.

Comment: Also: there's no need to provide instructions for installing `azcopy` - the OP is *already using `azcopy`* (but they don't show any output or provide any additional details).

Comment: Thx for response. In my case, The storage account and container are not part of my Azure account. They are part of other account which is publicly accessible.